# How to hide particular data row in a datatable without deleting it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, windows-forms-designer, c#-to-vb.net

I want to hide a data row without deleting it in c# or vb.net. Please help me with this.
I want to hide a data row without deleting it in c# or vb.net.

```vb
ResultSelection.Checked = False ' Checkbox
Dim Dt As DataTable
Dim dr as datarow
Private SBind As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
With Dt
     .Columns.Add(" Name", GetType(String))
     .Columns.Add("Age" , GetType(integer))
     .Columns.Add("Marks" , GetType(integer))

dr(0) = ( "Mark",19,99)
dr(1) =  ( "Rahul",20,35)
dr(2) =  ( "Steve",19,50)

SBind.DataSource = Dt
DatargridView.DataSource = SBind

if ResultSelection.Checked = False then
    "entire row dr(2) should not be visible
else
    "entire data table should be visible along with dr(2)
end if
```

Comment: We need more explanation and some code.

Comment: A DataTable is just a way to store data in a logical way, not a visual

Comment: Thinking about what @Jules said, did you mean DataGridView instead of DataTable. Or is it that you are using DataTable as source for a DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide rows in a `DataTable` but you can in a `DataView`.  Every `DataTable` has a `DataView` associated with it by default, in its `DefaultView` property.  When you bind a `DataTable`, it is actually the `DefaultView` that the data comes from.  As such, you can set the `RowFilter` of that `DataView` in order to hide rows that don't match certain criteria.  For instance, if you had a `Sex` column that contained "Male" or "Female", you could hide all the "Male" rows like this:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Sex = 'Female'"
```

Any controls bound to that `DataTable` would not see the "Male" rows and you could loop through the `DataView` code to see the filtered data too.

If you are binding, I would recommend using a `BindingSource` in between, in which case you set its `Filter` property in the same way.